# How do I write Hebrew letters in a text object?

Tags: text-object

Is there a way to write Hebrew letters in a text object? I can't write Hebrew directly. I also tried to copy and paste letters with "Ctrl + v" but to no avail. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: hello, have you selected an hebrew font in the Text panel?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast reply:) I was confused, when I added the text object I could write in English, but when I switched to Hebrew, it just didn't work. Turned out like you said I needed to select the Hebrew font first:) lol. Thank you for your fast reply!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly,
I can only test it by c&p because I don't have a hebrew keyboard layout.

But i have downloaded a hebrew font here
and pasted it into Blender
https://alefalefalef.co.il/en/resources/

And was able to insert hebrew characters . see screenshot.

[image]

Kind regards Sebastian